# How can I generate complex table with angular js

Tags: angularjs

I have data like this :
`people = [{
        name: 'mary',
        item: [{tk:1},{fk:2},{ik:3}]
    }, {
        name: 'sano',
        item: [{tk:4},{fk:5},{ik:6}]
    }]`

And I would like to generate a table like this :

`mary sano
tk  1    4
fk  2    5
ik  3    6`

I am really beginner and I do know how should I generate the table with header.

Comment: Did you try anything? can you share your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will explain the tools you need.  Rather than using a magic library, you should do this manually to learn.

Use **ng-repeat** to loop through the people elements, and display the "name" values.  You can output the values using the {{ }} syntax

```
<table>
  <tbody ng-repeat="person in people">
      <th>
      {{person.name}}
      </th>
  </tbody>
     .. rest of code here
</table>
```

You can use this pattern to render the rest of the data values.